# Getting error when trying to run Data loader on Mac

Tags: data-loader

I just downloaded the Data Loader from salesforce (mac version) on my machine.
Now when I try to run it, it's giving me the error:

> Please make sure that the config file: /Volumes/DataLoader/Data
>   Loader.app/Contents/Resources/conf/config.properties exists and is
>   writable.

Can anyone please help me figure out where these files are located/ work around it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, and resolved it by making sure I installed the Data Loader application into `/Applications` and not somewhere else. There is also a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jeJxAAI) on this which you can report as affecting you.

Comment: I moved the new one but it still didn't work as the old version (with old logo) was getting copied over (i have no idea how) when I used the default Mac UI for moving new applications to "Applications". Nevertheless, I tried to copy, it created old version of the dataloader, i tried to copy again and chose "Keep Both" and this copied over the new version. I then deleted the old version and it's working fine now.